# U-Boot: read-only environment variables

Tags: c, boot, bootloader, u-boot, setenv

In U-Boot how should we configure an environment variable during boot up that would be just read-only. IOW `setenv` on this variable (in the U-Boot console or pragmatically) should not be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to modify U-Boot source code.
`ethaddr` has a similar characteristic; once set, `ethaddr` cannot be modified. This characteristic is hardcoded.